# Why my standard input not consider the flower brackets using perl?

Tags: perl

Here I had tried to read the file using standard input. In my case standard input fails to print the flower bracket contents.

My code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'file.txt';
open my $fh, "<", $file
    or die "Could not open '$file': $!";
chomp(my @files = <$fh>);
close $fh
    or die "Coould not close '$file' $!";
while (my $stdin = <>) {
    chomp $stdin;
    if ( grep { $stdin eq $_ } @files ) {
        print "@files\n";
        last
    }
    else {
        print "There is no word in the $file\n";
        last;
    }
}
```

File.txt:

```
{data1}
data2
data3
{data4}
```

File Execution:

```
perl t.pl
data1
There is no word in the file.txt
```

Comment: `{data1}` will never be equal to `data1`!

Comment: You are comparing the two strings for equality, and `'data1' eq '{data1}'` is *false*.

Comment: Here then how i can check string comparison.If it is string comparison the tutorial says eq.@MattJacob

Comment: Maybe you want a regular expression instead?

Comment: `user entered - data1 output - {data1} data2 data3 {data4}  
user entered - {data1} output - {data1} data2 data3 {data4}`

Comment: what is OP's expection

Comment: @srv vani, Re "*how i can check string comparison*", You *are* performing a string comparison. But that's obviously not what you want, since `data1` and `{data1}` are different strings. Do you perhaps want to check if `$input` is *contained in* `$_` instead?

Comment: They're called "braces" or "curly brackets," not "flower brackets."

Comment: @jwodder The terminology is the least of the OP's problems.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this question has been edited since I first looked at it a few hours ago. Originally, the crucial line looked like this:

```
if ( grep { $stdin eq $_ } @files ) {
```

That was never going to work because you are giving it "data1" as input and none of the lines matches that string using `eq`. You have a line that contains "data1", but as it is surrounded by "{" and "}", the strings are different - `'data1` eq `{data1}` is obviously false.

You have now changed that line to:

```
if ( grep { $stdin && $_ } @files ) {
```

And that's very strange. This check asks the question "do both `$stdin` and `$_` contain true values?". And that will almost certainly always be true. I'm really not sure what that change was supposed to achieve.

Your question doesn't actually say what you're trying to do here. But I'm guessing that you want to match if any of the lines contains the string that is entered (but it's ok if it doesn't make up the entire line). In that case, you want a regex check and your line of code should be:

```
if ( grep { /\Q$stdin/ } @files ) {
```

**Note:** I've added the `\Q` as suggested in the comments. This is a good idea as it prevents the strings in `@files` being interpreted as containing regex metacharacters.

Comment: more likely `/\Q$stdin/`, unless `@files` is supposed to contain regexes